# how to completely fix an image on one relative point css

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm not sure how to fix this: image directly positioned underneath some text, and stays directly underneath that text when the window is resized. My problem is I can't just float the image left, it needs to be further out, and move inline with some text. Like centring an image, it will always stay in the relative centre, even when the page is resized.

**EDIT:** I think the problem is I have 3 sections of text next to each other formatted like this, and they move when the page is resized:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css"/>
<p>this is the text which the image should follow (stay inline with)
</p>
<p>third section middle</p>
<p>third section right</p>
<img src="https://codepo8.github.io/canvas-images-and-pixels/img/horse.png"/>
```

CSS:

```
p{
  float:left;
  width:33.33333%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2A3132;
}
img{
  width: 10%;
}
```

And I want that image to stay in the centre of that text when the page is resized. I hope this helps.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put inside of the parent `content`

```css
.content{
  background: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
p{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  width:33.33333%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2A3132;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
img{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>this is the text which the image should follow (stay inline with)</p>
  <p>third section middle</p>
  <p>third section right</p>
  <img src="http://devimg.com/100x100/"/>
</div>
```